# Validation functions are undefined

Tags: javascript, validation

I created a function:

```
function createValidatorForForm(id) {
    var formValidator = $(id).validate({
        errorClass:'help-inline',
        errorElement:'p',

        highlight:function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element.parentNode.parentNode).addClass('error')
        },
        unhighlight:function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element.parentNode.parentNode).removeClass('error')
        }
    });
    return formValidator;}
```

and then I use it in my code in the next way:

```
var reportValidator = createValidatorForForm("#report-form");
var areaValidator = createValidatorForForm("#area-form");
var liquidationValidator = createValidatorForForm("#liquidation-form");
var comparableValidator = createValidatorForForm("#comparable-form");
```

but though Firebug knows about formValidator and I can see it's state in debugger, he alerts me that reportValidator and another three variables are undefined and I can't use them in my code: reportValidator.form() generates an error. But validation itself works on all forms.

```
function saveReport() {
if (!comparableValidator.form()){return};
$.ajax({
    url : SAVE_REPORT, // + "?json=" + ko.toJSON(reportModel),
    data : {
        json : ko.toJSON(reportModel)
    }, ...
```

Comment: what is reportValidator.form()? please, show full code how you call validators

Comment: Validate is not a standard Jquery function. Which lib are you using?

Comment: Are you calling `createValidatorForForm` in jquery.ready callback? Like `$(document).ready(function() {...var reportValidator = createValidatorForForm("#report-form");...})`

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator - that's the lib I'm using.

Comment: 2FAngel, no, not exactly, I'm using it in onDocumentReady() function.

Comment: And where do you call reportValidator.form()? Outside that function, right?

Comment: yes, in button onclick function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
   reportValidator = createValidatorForForm("#report-form");
   areaValidator = createValidatorForForm("#area-form");
   liquidationValidator = createValidatorForForm("#liquidation-form");
   comparableValidator = createValidatorForForm("#comparable-form");
```

Now `reportValidator` and other variables are global and visible outside `onDocumentReady` callback function. If you put a `var` you make variables local and available inside `onDocumentReady` callback function only.

Comment: TypeError: comparableValidator is undefined
if (!comparableValidator.form()){return}; - still not working

Comment: And scripts are not cached?

Comment: If that is not a caching issue, you may try `window.comparableValidator = createValidatorForForm("#comparable-form");` Code in answer should be a synonym to proposed here, but maybe there is something in your code that breaks it.

Comment: stop, excuse me, I was wrong, only comparableValidator is undefined, all other work well, thank you very much

Comment: Well, I see nothing wrong with your code. Possibly you are passing wrong form id or something else. Not clear